# CSS3 PIE doesn't work with border-radius and box-shadow

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

I've coded a simple html/css for testing purposes and I can't get the library to work.
I've moved the .htc, .php and .js files to the same directory of index.html and it doesn't work at all.

[Link to the code.](http://jsfiddle.net/smhkf/)

All files are in the same directory of index.html, are accessible via URL, and I believe that should be enough to work.
I've already tried putting the behavior tag and position: relative, z-index:0 in the css file but IE can't see these properties.

The Code: **HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script src='PIE.js'></script>
<body>
<div>test</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**:

```
 div {
     float: left;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 0;
     width: 300px;
     height: 300px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
     -moz-borderradius: 10px;
     border-radius: 10px;
     -pie-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #000;
     box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #000;
     behavior: url(PIE.htc);
     background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: A problem I often run into with CSS3 PIE is my server not recognizing the .htc content type. If you're using apache, try adding `AddType text/x-component .htc` to your .htaccess file. http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#content-type

Comment: Hello Dan. I'm using NGINX at production server but this test was done in my machine, no server, just a simple directory with these files: index.html, index.css, PIE.js, PIE.php and jquery.js.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it.
The problem were several things.

How it worked:

1. I'm testing on IE10 but I hadn't activated the Navigate Mode, only Document Mode IE8. So just activate Navigate Mode IE8.
2. Import script PIE.js. .htc or .php doesn't matter.
3. Set the element styles one by one with `position: relative` and `z-index: 0`

That's it.
Tnks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the order in which you set the different browser-compatibility rules is important:

```
border-radius
then -moz
then -ms
then -webkit
```

I had them in a different order and it wouldn't work...

Maybe it will help someone...